# Strong Induction Proof Verification (n as a sum of 4s and 7s)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I wanted to verify whether not my attempt at the following proof is okay or not:

Claim: Every natural number n ≥ 18 can be written as a sum of 4s and 7s.

My attempt:

**Base cases:**

n = 18 = 4 + 7(2)

n = 19 = 4(3) + 7

n = 20 = 4(5)

n = 21 = 7(3)

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that for k ≥ 21, each number from 18...k can be written as a sum of 4s and 7s. For k+1, write it as (k-3) + 4. k-3 does, in fact, fall between 18...k so (k-3) can be written as a sum of 4s and 7s. Now just add 4 to express k + 1 as a sum of 4s and 7s. QED

Comment: You are totally right.

Comment: I agree you're correct. FYI, the more general case of your problem is the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: More generally, given two relatively prime positive integers, a and b, all integers greater than (a-1)(b-1) can be expressed as ma+nb for non-negative integers m and n.